# Как сделать bat файл, который автоматически отвечает дальше на вопросы

Tags: powershell, bat, скрипт

мне нужно выполнять работу одной команды в PowerShell на полном автомате.

Я пытался сделать таким путем - но оно не отвечает на первый же вопрос.

```
powershell.exe "iwr "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Vencord/Installer/main/install.ps1" -UseBasicParsing | iex"
timeout 2
echo 2
timeout 8
echo 5
```

Первый вопрос, где нужно ответить цифрой "2", что бы дальше продолжилась загрузка, а после ответ дать цифру "5". Но ничего не происходит, как я могу сделать этот код рабочим?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Отредактируйте установщик так, чтобы он не запрашивал ввод пользователя так будет легче.

Comment: А дёрнуть `VencordInstallerCli.exe` с ключом `--help` - не спасёт отца русской демократии?